# Utterly confused by Ajax

Tags: ajax

Okay, so I think i'm doing this wrong. I just started working with jquery and Ajax and cannot find any real good tutorials. so i'm basically working off Jquery code i've found and trying to get it to work.

Could someone explain to me why this isn't working?
(the login.php file is just a login script that returns "true" if it was run successfully and "false" if it fails).

```
<?php
include('./includes/config.php');
echo $_SESSION['uid'];
?>
<a href='logout.php'>logout</a>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id='login_form'>
<input type='text' name='username' id='username'> 
<input type='password' name='password' id='password'>
<input type='submit' id='submit'>
</form>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('#login_form').submit(
function()
{
    $.ajax({
        type:POST, 
        url:'login.php', 
        success: function(){alert('win!')}
    })
})
</script>
```

Comment: Clarify "isn't working"

Comment: you have a lot of syntax error. type:POST should be type:'POST' and don't forget semicolons.

Comment: Yes, please give more details than that

Comment: "isn't working" as it "not doing anything" as in "does not login the user" as in "the code doesn't work."

Comment: @user1030841: still not helpful. Have you tried to open js console? Any js debugger to see the ajax request is sent?

Comment: none of the JS debuggers are throwing any errors or anything. The code just doesn't work.

Comment: i've fixed the 'post' and STILL the code DOES NOT WORK.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, it should be type:'POST' or type:"POST", not type:POST.

The official explanation page is actually quite good:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
Just grab some of the sample code from there.